# Function Key issue with selenium

Tags: selenium, java, selenium-ide

How to press function keys like F12 using selenium (java). Please help me in this.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a trivial question that could be answered with a simple web search

Comment: This question in its current form lacks a show of effort. (It actually isn't off-topic, but that's the only real close reason that allows a custom message...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
you can easily do that using:
Robot rt = new Robot();
rt.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F12);
```